# Constructing k-wise independent variables over a general set

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, finite-fields, random-functions

We have seen in class a polynomials based construction that builds in $O(n^k)$ time, $n$ random variables, $k$-wise independent, over a field with $n$ elements. More specifically, you generate all the $n^k$ sets of $k$-long vectors over the field. Then they have the property of $k$-wise independence.

My question is, can we push it further? suppose that $p < n$. Could I generate in $O(n^k)$ time, $n$ random variables, $k$-wise independent, over a field with $p < n$ elements?

I thought of constructing first the $n$ variables over a field with $n$ elements, and then 'contract' them to the field with $p$, but I think that could cause a problem with the $k$ wise independence.
Suppose contracting $Z_7$ to $Z_5$, some of the $7^k$ elements will be mapped to the same $5^k$ elements, and that would affect the independence.

For example, in the from $Z_3$ to $Z_2$, suppose I have
$(a,b) \in (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)$
and that maps to
$(a,b) \in (0,0), (0,1), (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,0), (0,1), (0,0)$
which is no longer pairwise independent - $Pr[b = 0 | a = 0] = 4/9$, while $Pr[b = 0 | a = 1] = 2/9$

So is there a way to do it? Perhaps necessarily there's isn't?

thanks

Comment: I had a similar question and found section 4.1 of https://www.csc.kth.se/~johanh/verktyg/lecture3.pdf helpful.